# Getting NaN values while trying to convert FITS file to ndarray using astropy

Tags: python, astropy

I am trying to convert a FITS file to a ndarray using astropy. I am following these [instructions](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/). I am using [fv tool](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftools/fv/fv_download.html) to look at the image in the FITS file but the table of the file is filled with only Null values:[image]
I got this FITS file from [here](http://jsoc.stanford.edu/SUM93/D1245657400/S00000/hmi.Ic_720s.20191218_231200_TAI.3.continuum.fits). I get NaN values in my jupyter notebook too when I follow the instructions given in the link:

```
image_file = 'http://jsoc.stanford.edu/SUM93/D1245657400/S00000/hmi.Ic_720s.20191218_231200_TAI.3.continuum.fits'
hdulist = fits.open(image_file)
hdulist.info() 

### output:

Filename: C:\Users\yatin\.astropy\cache\download\py3\dd629fe158baf0b180d1835a3227eac4
No.    Name      Ver    Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
  0  PRIMARY       1 PrimaryHDU       6   ()      
  1                1 CompImageHDU    106   (4096, 4096)   int16   

hdulist.verify('fix')

 ### output:
WARNING: VerifyWarning: HDU 1: [astropy.io.fits.verify]
WARNING: VerifyWarning:     Card 74: [astropy.io.fits.verify]
WARNING: VerifyWarning:         Card 'CRDER1' is not FITS standard (invalid value string: 'nan').  Fixed 'CRDER1' card to meet the FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify]
WARNING: VerifyWarning:     Card 75: [astropy.io.fits.verify]
WARNING: VerifyWarning:         Card 'CRDER2' is not FITS standard (invalid value string: 'nan').  Fixed 'CRDER2' card to meet the FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify]
WARNING: VerifyWarning:     Card 76: [astropy.io.fits.verify]
WARNING: VerifyWarning:         Card 'CSYSER1' is not FITS standard (invalid value string: 'nan').  Fixed 'CSYSER1' card to meet the FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify]
WARNING: VerifyWarning:     Card 77: [astropy.io.fits.verify]
WARNING: VerifyWarning:         Card 'CSYSER2' is not FITS standard (invalid value string: 'nan').  Fixed 'CSYSER2' card to meet the FITS standard. [astropy.io.fits.verify]

hdulist[1].data

### output:
array([[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       ...,
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]], dtype=float32)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried opening the file with `fitsio` and I am able to read `hdu[1]` data without a problem. Can you try removing the 'fix' step?

Comment: I tried installing fitsio but pip and conda both failed me...As for astropy, without the 'fix' step I get an error asking me to 'fix' when i try doing hdulist[1].data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a non-answer, but it doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong. I downloaded the same file and while parts of it contain NaNs, parts of it don't. When you print the data for a 4096x4096 image it's not going to show all the values, and it seems most of the values around the borders are NaNs (perhaps an aperture cut-out?).  For example:

```
>>>> np.isnan(hdulist[1].data).all()
False
```

I can see some of the points where are non-NaN like:

```
>>> np.where(~np.isnan(hdulist[1].data))
(array([  19,   19,   19, ..., 4069, 4069, 4069]),
 array([2025, 2026, 2027, ..., 2092, 2093, 2094]))
```

In fact it seems there are quite a few non-NaN values:

```
>>> len(np.where(~np.isnan(hdulist[1].data))[0])
12887376
```

When in doubt, try plotting your data with matplotlib.  By default it will treat NaNs as just blank pixels:

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> plt.imshow(hdulist[1].data)
```

I get:

[image]

Indeed, the NaNs just looks like an aperture cut-out.

The only one that's doing anything "wrong" is whatever software wrote this FITS file, since I don't think the FITS standard technically provides a way to represent `inf` and `nan` values in header keywords, even though it probably should...

Comment: Remember, just because at a first glance some preview of the raw data is showing all NaNs in one corner doesn't mean the whole array is NaN-filled.

Answer (score 1):

I also have had the same problem. This looks like Solar Dynamics Observatory HMI continuum images or similar. As you already know they use *nan* for some CARD values which are not supported by the  astropy.io.fits package (version 4.0.1). I have posted a bug/problem report with the  [astropy community](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/10153). The report also includes details of a quick hack fix you can make to your installation of astropy.io.fits code until a real fix comes out.  The hack  provides support for nan.